# Lubuntu 15.10 MAME 0.160 Issue

Tags: drivers, graphics, lubuntu, intel-graphics, mame

I'm trying to figure out why there is an error when I load the following in terminal:

```
$ mame
libGL error: failed to create dri screen
libGL error: failed to load driver: i915

$ locate *i915*
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/i915_dri.so

$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: 
Intel Corporation 82865G Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
Subsystem: Dell Dimension 3000
Kernel driver in use: i915

$ inxi -Fxz

System:    Host: lubuntucarecomplex-Dimension-3000 Kernel: 4.2.0-30-generic i686 (32 bit gcc: 5.2.1)
           Desktop: LXDE (Openbox 3.6.1) Distro: Ubuntu 15.10 wily
Machine:   System: Dell product: Dimension 3000
           Mobo: Dell model: 0N6381 Bios: Dell v: A03 date: 01/05/2006
CPU:       Single core Intel Celeron (-UP-) cache: 256 KB
           flags: (pae sse sse2 sse3) bmips: 4788 speed: 2394 MHz (max)
Graphics:  Card: Intel 82865G Integrated Graphics Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.17.2 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1280x1024@60.02hz
           GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.8, 128 bits)
           GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 11.3.0-devel (git-aa3b85f 2016-02-28 wily-oibaf-ppa) Direct Rendering: Yes

$ fglrxinfo
libGL error: failed to create dri screen
libGL error: failed to load driver: i915
display: :0.0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.8, 128 bits)
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 11.3.0-devel (git-aa3b85f 2016-02-28 wily-oibaf-ppa)

$ LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxgears
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/tls/i915_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/i915_dri.so
libGL error: failed to create dri screen
libGL error: failed to load driver: i915
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
379 frames in 5.0 seconds = 75.693 FPS
618 frames in 5.0 seconds = 123.481 FPS
621 frames in 5.0 seconds = 124.021 FPS
620 frames in 5.0 seconds = 123.817 FPS
^C

$ sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
**xserver-xorg-video-intel is already the newest version.**
xserver-xorg-video-intel set to manually installed.
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libllvm3.6v5
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

Here's the solution I figured out and removed my error:

```
sudo apt-get remove libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
```

Doing this showed some unmet dependencies [The clue I needed] and wouldn't let me uninstall this package without removing the ppa. I figured I'd start removing drivers to see what the issue was, it was the next step to troubleshoot this issue.

*Wine **MUST** be installed when you do the oibaf PPA for this to work*

**I removed the following two ppa repositories:**

**ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates [I did this one in LXDE Start Menu > Preferences > Additional Drivers > Other Software [TAB]**

```
$ sudo ppa-purge ppaibaf/graphics-drivers [Terminal]

**The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:**
libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-dev libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1 
libdrm2 libegl1-mesa libegl1-mesa-dev libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dri 
libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libosmesa6 libva-x11-1 libva1 libvdpau1 
libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2 libvorbisfile3 libwayland-egl1-mesa 
libxatracker2 mesa-utils mesa-vdpau-drivers xserver-xorg-video-ati 
xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-nouveau 
xserver-xorg-video-radeon 
The following NEW packages will be installed:
libllvm3.6v5{a} 
The following packages will be REMOVED:
libllvm3.8{u} libomxil-bellagio-bin{u} libomxil-bellagio0{u} 
vdpau-driver-all{u} 
The following packages are RECOMMENDED but will NOT be installed:
i965-va-driver va-driver-all vdpau-va-driver 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 27 downgraded, 4 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

dpkg: warning: downgrading libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 from 11.3~git1602290730.07ed00~gd~w to 11.0.2-1ubuntu4
Preparing to unpack .../libgl1-mesa-dri_11.0.2-1ubuntu4_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (11.0.2-1ubuntu4) over (11.3~git1602290730.07ed00~gd~w) ...
```

Since Lubuntu 15.10 had some recent updates again regarding all the mesa driver packages, it was time to revert from the drivers I originally had working from those ppa repositories.

I still kept the following packages above and added this one from the unmet dependencies shown in the remove prompt:

```
sudo apt-get install kde-runtime
```

[Leaving it installed since it system is working well now]

I added `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio` to remove ALSA pcm errors I was having when it was the other ppa driver installed, just throwing that in extra.

All the other applications I had installed previously like mesa-utils, etc., did downgrade to official Ubuntu packages and now the issue is resolved!

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep mesa
libegl1-mesa:i386                install
libegl1-mesa-dev:i386                install
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386                install
libgl1-mesa-glx:i386                install
libglapi-mesa:i386                install
libglu1-mesa:i386                install
libosmesa6:i386                    install
libwayland-egl1-mesa:i386            install
mesa-utils                    install
mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386                install


$ mame -mt -video opengl -rs -speed 1.00

Average speed: 68.03% (185 seconds)
```

**Now MAME is working correctly with the -Video OpenGL option [No more -Video Soft needed!] Errors gone!**

DRICONF showing Mesa Driver Working now: [Mesa Driver Loaded/Active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSRjm.png)

FINAL EDIT: So after a reboot, the issue returned.

FINAL FIX: I duplicated the error/fix

```
[intel_do_flush_locked_failed:input output error/libGL error: failed to create dri screen
libGL error: failed to load driver: i915
```

by re-adding the oibaf ppa, then doing *LXDE Start Menu > System Tools > Software Updater* to get the PPA software updates needed, then ppa purge again to figure out it was the Intel Driver I needed!

**Used this link:** https://launchpad. net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers/+packages

**Installed these two from the link above and now everything is COMPLETE/WORKING!**

1. `xserver-xorg-video-intel-dbg_2.99.917+git1602241932.d16728~gd~w_i386.deb` (2.6 MiB)
2. `xserver-xorg-video-intel_2.99.917+git1602241932.d16728~gd~w_i386.deb` (1.6 MiB)

Hope this helps someone with MAME who tries to get it working, and runs into this issue running it installing/configuring from Terminal.